# Comparing arrays in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a collection in mongo which has array field. When I query that collection I want to return documents whose elements in the array field represent a `subset` of the array I'm comparing with. So all array elements in the document that satisfies the condition should also be present in the array I'm comparing with but that array can have additional elements.

In this case document with ArrayField satisfies condition

```
    'ArrayField' => 
  array (
    'KeyA' => 'ValueA',
    'KeyB' => 'ValueB',
    'KeyC' => 'ValueC'
  )

'ComparedArray' => 
  array (
    'KeyA' => 'ValueA',
    'KeyB' => 'ValueB',
    'KeyC' => 'ValueC',
    'KeyD' => 'ValueD',
  )
```

In this case document does not satisfy the condition

```
'ArrayField' =>
  array (
    'KeyA' => 'ValueA',
    'KeyB' => 'ValueB',
    'KeyC' => 'ValueC'
  )

'ComparedArray' => 
  array (
    'KeyA' => 'ValueA',
    'KeyB' => 'ValueB',
  )
```

I'm really stuck and can't find a way how to write this query. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documents we want can be obtained by:

- Checking for documents where the `arrayField` does not have an element,
  that is not present in the `comparedArray`.
- use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and [$nin](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operators to find at least one element that is present in `arrayField` but not in `comparedArray`.
- Apply a negative condition using [$not](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) operrator, to the above to get the documents that we want.

Code:

```
db.collection.find({"arrayField":
                              {$not:
                                 {$elemMatch:
                                    {$nin:comparedArray}}}})
```

PHP:

```
$notIn= array('$nin'=>comparedArray);
$eleMatch= array('$elemMatch' => $notIn);
$not = array('$not' => $eleMatch);
$collection -> find(array("arrayField" => $not);
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for, thank you. I have an additional question regarding these arrays. It seems that this only works when I have non-associative key-value pairs in the arrays I am comparing. If I have associative arrays it doesn't work as expected. How can I make this work with associative arrays?